# How to resize image with custom size

Tags: android, android-image

I need to resize my image with custom size. The image is taken from device camera or gallery, i tired the below code, but the image is stretched, i need the image in square shape with out any stretch.

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Bitmap bm, int boundBoxInDp) {
boundBoxInDp=300;
        int height = bm.getHeight();
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        float scaleWidth = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / width;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) boundBoxInDp) / height;
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
                matrix, false);
        return resizedBitmap;

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a bitmap, you could use the following code to resize:

```
Bitmap originalBitmap = <original initialization>;

Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, newWidth, newHeight, false);
```

Or you can use following library for resize image

https://github.com/biokys/cropimage

Answer (score 1):

This won't fit your image in a bounding box (the failure of which is presumably what you're calling "stretch"). It will not handle rectangular bitmaps in your square bounding box, nor will it handle images smaller than the bounding box particularly well. You probably want something like:

```
public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromFile(Bitmap bm, int boundBoxInDp) {
    boundSquareInPx=convertToPixels(300);
    int maxDimen = Math.max(bm.getHeight(), bm.getWidth())
    float scale = (maxDimen <= boundSquareInPx) ? 1 : boundSquareInPx / (float) maxDimen;
    float scaleWidth = scale * bm.getWidth();
    float scaleHeight = scale * bm.getHeight();
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, true);
    return resizedBitmap;

}
```

Few notes: if you image is smaller than your bound it won't fit it- obvious modifications do that.

Secondly, dp != px; the `Bitmap` object returns px, so you're going to have to convert to px from dp (which is well documented elsewhere).

Use `postTranslate(...)` if you need to center the correspondingly cropped bitmap.

The documentation is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/package-summary.html); this *is* allready the best library I know for resizing in Android- I've never needed anything else, and I've been in the game a while and work with this frequently.

If you need, in my opinion, the best introduction to working with the API efficiently: read the source code to [ImageView](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/ImageView.java) and `Drawable` instances; a really worthwhile personal development exercise would be to use the SDK to implement a fading transition drawable that is center cropped, as that's rather annoyingly one of the only things missing from the Android library, and would involve a heck of a lot of the kind of coding you're trying to do above.

**NB:**

As you'll note, another answerer has pointed out the existence of `createScaledBitmap`, which is probably much clearer code; I just wanted to point out how what you were doing was basically right and how it could be improved.

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/coomar2841/image-chooser-library/blob/d27b542d2487132b0150be382f39e9ef95aafe68/src/com/kbeanie/imagechooser/threads/MediaProcessorThread.java.

The method called `compressAndSaveImage`.